# RStudio wont start after updating R - error after updating R

Tags: r, rstudio

So I am running RStudio on a Mac (10.9.4).
I wanted to update my old R to 3.1.0.
I was trying to follow instructions I found on Stacked Overflow.

I downloaded the .pkg file for R-3.1.0 from CRAN and followed the installer instructions.
- I went to ~/Library/R and copied and renamed the folder containing my libraries
ie. now I have ~/Library/R/3.0 and ~/Library/R/3.1
- I shut down my computer and restarted it.

Now when I try to start RStudio (either through the terminal or through the icon) I am getting an error that it can't find details to check on package updates. 
"Error Checking for Updates (TypeError) 'null' is not an object evaluating 'c[a]'"

Then it crashes saying it encountered a fatal error.

I also tried installing the new RStudio.

update:  It looks like there is an error when I try to start the new R from my terminal.

I get the following error:

```
Warning: namespace ‘Biobase’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘Golub_Merge’

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
3: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
4: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
5: loadNamespace(name)
6: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
8: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
9: tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) {    warning(gettextf("namespace %s is not available and has been replaced\nby .GlobalEnv when processing object %s",         sQuote(name)[1L], sQuote(where)), domain = NA, call. = FALSE,         immediate. = TRUE)    .GlobalEnv})
10: ..getNamespace(c("ggplot2", "1.0.1"), "Ip")
11: load(name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
12: sys.load.image(".RData", FALSE)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Knowing the current R version is 3.2.0

Comment: yes I do know this, but in the past I"ve found that not all packages have been updated to work with the most recent version.

Comment: @Pascal more 3.2.1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay - to answer the error with R.
I deleted teh .RData file, assuming it required too much memory.

Now RStudio starts.

I still have a problem with my packages, but I'll post a new question.